# Why is my ArrayList empty once I pass it to my other class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on a chat room project, I'm trying to populate a section of a GUI with an ArrayList from another class, I've attempted to use a JList as well as JTextArea but for some reason, my ArrayList is always empty once it has been passed to the next class. I've been stuck for a few days now and I've researched a LOT and gone through many of these similar threads and not found my answer.

**Server Class**

```
    private static ArrayList<ClientInfo> clients = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();
    private static ArrayList<String> membersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    

    public static void memberlist() {
        for (ClientInfo userName : clients) {
            if (!membersList.contains(userName.getName())) {
                membersList.add(userName.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    
    public ArrayList<String> getMembers() {
        System.out.println("This was called from another class");
        return membersList;
    }

            clients.add(new ClientInfo(name, ClientID++, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort()));
            memberlist();
```

So I had a clients ArrayList but I needed a list with just the usernames so I created another ArrayList called membersList, in this I used a for loop to take the names out of the clients list and put them in my new one then I created a getter method which should return those names.

The last bit is inside a seperate method in that same class which adds the client info then after I call the memberlist method.

**ClientWindow Class**

```
    private static JTextArea membersList = new JTextArea();


        Server members = new Server();
        membersList.setEditable(false);
        membersList.append(members.getMembers() + "\n");
        System.out.println(membersList);
```

In my GUI class I created a JTextArea and tried to populate it with the ArrayList getter method but the arraylist is always empty once it's been passed to my GUI class, I was using JList before to do this and I had the exact same result and then my friend told me the list was empty because I was using .toArray to convert the ArrrayList. The list always contains the usernames when it prints in the server class but once it reaches the ClientWindow class it's empty. So I attempted to use a JTextArea thinking I solved the issue but once again the list is empty.

**Previous JList Code**

```
    private JList<String> activeMembers;

        Server members = new Server();
        activeMembers = new JList<String>(members.getMembers().toArray(new String[0]));
        activeMembers.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        activeMembers.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Any help will be appreciated, my first post on this website so I'm sorry if I made anything unclear.
(ps: also very new to coding)

Comment: If the method ```setEditable(false)``` does what it sounds like, wouldn't it stop you from appending to your list in the line after it in your ```ClientWindow``` class?

Comment: I only added that after, it did the same thing with it being set on True

Comment: @bdehmer actually, `setEditable(false)` only avoids editing on the GUI, that is, by the user;  `append` should work normally.